# Apache Camel: SFTP endpoint - Pipe closed issue

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am working with a route which downloads files from a remote server to local directory using SFTP.

Apache Camel version: 2.15.2 
From endpoint: sftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx//User/User01?delay=30s&include=File.*.csv&initialDelay=1m&password=xxxxxx&stepwise=false&streamDownload=true&username=User01 
To endpoint: file:///var/opt/myfolder/incoming?doneFileName=${file:name}.done

The remote location has more than 10 files available for download. After downloading 2-3 files, the route gets stuck and after around 30 seconds I get the below error in logs:

```
DEBUG 04/11/15 07:45:24,183 org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations :Using InputStream to write file: /var/opt/myfolder/incoming/File01.csv 
... 
around 30 secs gap 
... 
INFO 04/11/15 07:49:53,820 org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations$JSchLogger :JSCH -> Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Connection reset 
INFO 04/11/15 07:49:53,821 org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations$JSchLogger :JSCH -> Disconnecting from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port xx 
WARN 04/11/15 07:49:53,823 org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper :Cannot close: File01.csv. Reason: Pipe closed 
java.io.IOException: Pipe closed 
        at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:308) 
        at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:378) 
        at java.io.InputStream.skip(InputStream.java:222) 
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.skip(ChannelSftp.java:2894) 
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.access$600(ChannelSftp.java:36) 
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$RequestQueue.cancel(ChannelSftp.java:1246) 
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$2.close(ChannelSftp.java:1503) 
        at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.close(IOHelper.java:326) 
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.writeFileByStream(FileOperations.java:404) 
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.storeFile(FileOperations.java:274) 
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.writeFile(GenericFileProducer.java:277) 
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.processExchange(GenericFileProducer.java:165) 
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.process(GenericFileProducer.java:79) 
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61) 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:129) 
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77) 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448) 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191) 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118) 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80) 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:111) 
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77) 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448) 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191) 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118) 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80) 
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109) 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:60) 
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:166) 
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:435) 
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileConsumer.processExchange(RemoteFileConsumer.java:137) 
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:211) 
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:175) 
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:174) 
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:101) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I have set redelivery so it re attempts the download. The reattempt happens for the last file and as per the logs the file is downloaded. But when i check the folder the file size is 0 and even the .done file is created, the actual file size on remote server is 28 KB. 
For rest of the files i get the below error for each file and none of the file is downloaded:

```
WARN 04/11/15 07:49:58,877 org.slf4j.helpers.MarkerIgnoringBase :Error processing file RemoteFile[/User/User01/File02.csv] due to Cannot retrieve file: /User/User01/File02.csv. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException - Cannot retrieve file: /User/User01/File02.csv] 
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot retrieve file: /User/User01/File02.csv 
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.retrieveFileToStreamInBody(SftpOperations.java:651) 
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.retrieveFile(SftpOperations.java:594) 
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:396) 
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileConsumer.processExchange(RemoteFileConsumer.java:137) 
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:211) 
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:175) 
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:174) 
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:101) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) 
Caused by: 4: 
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:1513) 
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:1266) 
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.retrieveFileToStreamInBody(SftpOperations.java:636) 
        ... 14 more 
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Pipe closed 
        at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:308) 
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel$MyPipedInputStream.updateReadSide(Channel.java:362) 
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:1287) 
        ... 16 more
```

I tried using both disconnect=true and false, the issue is happening in both the cases. 
Any suggestions what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You had used both **initial delay** which is the delay before polling for a file by the consumer and **delay** which is before the next poll. Both creates a time buffer which is

**Initialdelay+DownloadTime+Delay+WriteDestinationDirectoryTime**

1. Try using only "delay".
2. Try appending a timestamp to the file being stored in destination.
3. Try camel-ftp2